# Bluetooth Music Player

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am new to android, I want to know that is it possible for coding purpose that Play music in one android device and listen music in another device.

I want to develop application like Bluetooth music player.

If any one have idea then please share Code or link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps that you follow for above question:
1. Access Bluetooth programetically and pair two devices [This link give code sample and logic for same](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices) 
2. For playing music in another device you need to work with A2DP profile of bluetooth [(Api Link)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.html)

More over [See this example](http://derivedcode.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/connecting-to-a-bluetooth-a2dp-device-from-android/)